# Node.js reference error: index is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am building a chat application, and this index.js file is in the "routes" directory.  The error is on the first line.  There is also an index.jade file in the "views" directory.

```
module.exports.index = index;
module.exports.logon = logon;
module.exports.message = message;

exports.index = function index(req, res){
  res.render('index');
};

function logon(req, res){
  res.send('Logon');
};

function message(req, res){
  res.send('Message');
};
```

Comment: You don't ever create a variable named index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `exports` two times, also there is no variable `index`.

```
exports.index = function index(req, res){
  res.render('index');
};

module.exports.index = index;
```

try using

```
module.exports.index = index;

var index = function(req,res) {
  res.render('index');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a function to a variable, or you immediately call a function, you turn it from a statement into an expression.  This causes function hoisting to not happen.  You can fix the issue by not assigning the function `index` to `exports.index`, to restore the hoisting behavior:

```
function index(req, res){
  res.render('index');
};
```

You'll still have problem after that, because `logon` and `message` are not defined (you've defined `login` and `chat` instead).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm following a tutorial.  Before I had
`function index(req, res){
  res.send('Index');
};`
and then it said to change the index function to
`exports.index = function index(req, res){
  res.render('index');
};`
after creating an index.ejs file in the views directory, but I created an index.jade file instead.